# TeamCity Rest API Flaky test

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, cypress, teamcity

I am looking to retrieve a list of flaky tests and details from builds via TeamCity API. I don't have any leads. Please suggest better options to retrieve flaky tests from TeamCity.

[image: Flaky Test]

Comment: There is currently no public API to get that data. What we did was to inspect the network calls that the web page makes to their private endpoints and just called it directly ourselves with the appropriate credentials.